# Click on button doesn't insert value in database PHP

Tags: php, html, database

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a value in my database with PHP.
I'm a student, so I'm pretty new with PHP but I have been struggling with this for the past hours. I'm trying to insert a value in my database 'ic_likes' when I press on a image (that's within a button).

It's telling me this **error** but I'm not really sure what to do with it. I've been looking for it but can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong

> Notice: Undefined index: action in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/back-end/Development/collection.php on line 56*

My database looks like this:

**ic:**

```
=======================
       ic_items
=======================
id | items | text |url
=======================

==============
   ic_likes
==============
id | items_id 
==============
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <form class="" action="collection.php?id=<?php echo($items[0]['id'])?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insertLike" />
            <button type="submit" name="button">
                <img src="assets/img/like.svg" alt="Lost love in war" width="20" class="heart">
            </button>
        </form>
        <span class="info-txt aantal">

        <?php
            $aantalLikes = $likesDAO->getLikesForID($items[0]['id']);
            echo($aantalLikes['total']);
        ?>

        </span> 
    </li>   
</ul>
```

**collection.php**

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $likes = $likesDAO->selectByLikeId($item['id']);
}

if ($_POST['action'] == 'insertLike') {
    $data = array(
        'items_id' => $item['id']
    );
    $insertedLike = $likesDAO->insert($data);
    if (empty($insertedLike)) {
        $errors = $likesDAO->validate($data);
    }
}
```

**likeDAO.php**

```
public function insert($data) {
    $errors = $this->validate( $data );
    if (empty($errors)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `ic_likes` (`items_id`) VALUES (:items_id)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':items_id', $data['items_id']);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return $this->selectById($this->pdo->lastInsertId());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `collection.php` use `$_GET['id']` to get the ID that you're updating?

Comment: Your `$_POST['action']` doesn't have `action` index. Perhaps `isset($_POST['action'])`?

Comment: Is `collection.php` also displaying the HTML? You need to check if the form is being submitted before trying to use the POST parameters. When you open the page the first time none of the parameters are set.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Hi, thanks for the answer. It does indeed remove the error but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, collection.php does display the HTML. If I load the page there's nothing in the URL, when I click on the button it does add something in the url like 'collection.php?id=1' but I'd like to use that to insert that value in my DB, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: The code that uses `$item['id']` needs to be inside the `foreach ($items as $item)` loop.

Comment: But I don't understand how that loop relates to the ID in `?id=1`. Why do you need to loop over all item IDs when the ID is a parameter?

Comment: Hi, @Barmar it's definitely improving! :) Thanks a lot! So I've put the whole piece of code under the `foreach` in the `foreach` itself and when I press the button, they update. The problem now is that they all seem to update when I press on a button. They get one extra.

Comment: Why are you looping through all IDs instead of just the ID that was in the parameter?

Comment: @Barmar that's indeed the problem, but I don't really know how to get that specific ID actually... Sorry, it's al kind of new for me. I really appreciate the help

Comment: It's in `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a tutorial on form processing in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar awesome man, that's what I thought and I tried that but I accidentally put `;` behind it, but it's working now! Great man! Thank you so much. There's one more problem, it's updating 7 votes per click. I guess that's because of the foreach going through all the items. Is there a fix for that? Thank you so much again

Comment: Get rid of the foreach

Comment: @Barmar Oh, indeed, I can replace the `$item` by `$_GET['id']`. Awesome man! I can't thank you enough. Really appreciate the help! Have a great day!